# IPMI web management on Supermicro not working: "Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0:..." and "Invalid Channel 255"

Tags: ipmi, centos6.5, supermicro, ipmitool

Troubleshooting an IPMI issue on a centos 6.5 server.  Specifically, I am not able to set up IPMI web management due to errors when trying to work with IPMI LAN settings.

I get the following error when I type ipmitool lan print:

```
[root@]# ipmitool lan print
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Get Channel Info command failed
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Get Channel Info command failed
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Get Channel Info command failed
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Get Channel Info command failed
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Get Channel Info command failed
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Get Channel Info command failed
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Get Channel Info command failed
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Get Channel Info command failed
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Get Channel Info command failed
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Get Channel Info command failed
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Get Channel Info command failed
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Get Channel Info command failed
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Get Channel Info command failed
Invalid Channel 255
```

Almost all google/stackexchange answers to these problems result in the answer found here [ipmitool - can't find /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmidev/0](https://serverfault.com/questions/480371/ipmitool-cant-find-dev-ipmi0-or-dev-ipmidev-0), however this supermicro server has the same exact ipmi kernel modules loaded as my other supermicro server as shown below:

```
[root@SERVER_WITHOUT_WORKING_IPMI]# modprobe --showconfig | grep ipmi
alias platform:ipmi_si ipmi_devintf
[root@SERVER_WITH_WORKING_IPMI]# modprobe --showconfig | grep ipmi
alias platform:ipmi_si ipmi_devintf
```

Therefore, I suspect this is not a problem related to kernel modules...

Any assistance on this is greatly appreciated.  Note that this device is in production, so I have to be careful with "trying things out".  Also note that I am relatively new to linux (network engineer here).

Thanks everyone...(this is my first post!)

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  Please correct this back to a non-downvote so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the following:

```
lsmod | grep ipmi
```

...and this showed that the ipmi_devintf module was NOT loaded.  Did modprobe and loaded this and it worked.

However, I still can't ping the ipmi interface even though I verified correct network config <-- this is a separate problem that I will need to look into.