# IPMITool complains that /dev/ipmi0 doesn't exist, when it does

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ipmi, ipmitool

On my Ubuntu 16.04 server (Asrock E3C224D2I), I can't run `ipmitool`. It complains that it `Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory`.

Output of `ls /dev/ipmi*`:

`# ls /dev/ipmi*
/dev/ipmi0`

Output of `lsmod | grep -i ipmi`:

`# lsmod | grep -i ipmi
ipmi_ssif              24576  0
ipmi_si                57344  0
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler        49152  3 ipmi_ssif,ipmi_devintf,ipmi_si`

I can in fact navigate to the IPMI web interface, but can't log in as I don't know the password.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I assume you've already checked /dev/ipmi0 permissions?  Also, you're running as root?

Comment: Yup, running as root. Permissions on /dev/ipmi0 are crw-r--r--.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/480371/ipmitool-cant-find-dev-ipmi0-or-dev-ipmidev-0